# Поиск текста в файле Excel c# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Столкнулся с проблематикой реализации поиска текста ( буквенных и числовых значений ) в файле excel.
Суть такова : изначально пользователь нажимает кнопку , с помощью которой выбирает excel-файл , в котором будет хранится текст в 1 столбце. После выбора файла пользователь вводит текст в textBox и по нажатию на другой button происходит поиск значения пользователя среди значений 1 столбца файла excel. Если значение найдено , вывести сообщение пользователю , в ином случае также вывод обязателен. Если же пользователь ищет один и тот же текст повторно , то в последующие разы вывести пользователю , что этот текст уже был ранее найден. Не умею понятия как реализовать проверку значения с text-Box-а со значениями с 1 столбца excel. Ну и соответственно как проверить , искался ли раньше определённый текст.

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется работа с файлом(в случае если он закрыт) рекомендую библиотеку
ClosedXML, она легка в освоении и имеет кучу примеров. Если необходимо работать в файлом в режиме "онлайн" следует использовать Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, но необходимо учитывать, что эта библиотека очень медленная и требует наличие Excel.
Для отслеживания истории удобно использовать Dictionary.